# Mysql autoincrement bug in insert select

Tags: mysql, select, insert, auto-increment

Can anyone suggest me the workaround for the following bug in mysql.

```
  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61058
```

This bug was reported long ago (2007) with mysql 5.0, but i am still facing same issue with mysql 5.6. I have followed this post which first gave some insight for this problem.

[Mysql auto increment jumps when insert-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226105/mysql-auto-increment-jumps-when-insert-select)

Followed the post as some one suggested preferably setting

```
ALTER TABLE `test` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

which will not work in my case where i have a stored procedure which will run in background as an event for a specified time.

Can anyone please suggest me for a workaround....??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, you should make sure that mysql is up to date and second try to reset auto increment like below:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Comment: ,as i said above same thing i tried in my stored procedure where i'll call the above code before doing Insert...select, but still the auto_increment column skips values..

Comment: You can contact with MySql support about this bug if you have already applied possible patchs or updates related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can change innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0 (“traditional” lock mode) from **mysql.ini** to  avoid skipping values in primary key in some cases. See the manual [innodb auto increment handling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html)  for more details.

> As per manual  'The traditional lock mode option is provided for backward compatibility, performance testing, and working around issues with “mixed-mode inserts”, due to possible differences in semantics'.
>
> 'In this lock mode, all “INSERT-like” statements obtain a special table-level AUTO-INC lock for inserts into tables with AUTO_INCREMENT columns. This lock is normally held to the end of the statement (not to the end of the transaction) to ensure that auto-increment values are assigned in a predictable and repeatable order for a given sequence of INSERT statements, and to ensure that auto-increment values assigned by any given statement are consecutive'.

Another thing to check is the value of the auto_increment_increment config variable. It's 1 by default, but you may have changed this. it is very uncommon to set it to something higher than 1 or 2, but possible.